# How to resolve error Object #<Object> has no method 'Router' in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
```

it gives an error

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'Router'
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/des0071/nodetest1/routes/index.js:6:35)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your express version

> Express router came in [express 4](https://github.com/expressjs/express/wiki/New-features-in-4.x)

After updating your express version then try to use it

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
```

Comment: how to separate files in express 2.5.8

Comment: `"how to separate files in express"`? what does it means?